# Best way to plug foundation vents?

Tags: foundation, vent

Whats the best way to close foundation vents? Closing the backdoor and then plug or using backdoor for better fit like second photo?

[image: CLosing back door and then putting foam plug]

[image: Using backdoor for better seal]

Comment: Are you closing them permanently, or just for the season?